# Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object in

Tags: php, mysql, ооп

Написал класс по работе с MySql, но с ошибкой. Новичок ещё)
Внутри класса есть функция, которая принимает три параметра(что делать, имя таблицы, массив).

Внутри этой функции я обрабатываю данные и делаю предварительный запрос на сервер, т.е. prepare.
Вот кусок кода:

```
$stmt = $this -> db -> prepare ("INSERT INTO $table ($rows) VALUES ($rows_prepare)");
$stmt -> bindParam($rows_prepareArray, $values_prepareArray);
$stmt -> execute();
```

Я так понял, что проблема в $this -> db

Как обратится к этому в этом же классе?

Comment: Нужно полное сообщение об ошибке в вопросе. Скорее всего у вас проблема в prepare и надо смотреть диагностический вывод по этому поводу.

Comment: Спасибо, значит ошибка тут
    for($i = 0; $i < count($rowsArray); $i++){
                    $stmt -> bindParam($rows_prepareArray[$i], $values_prepareArray[$i]);
                }

тут я устанавливаю параметры в цикле. Так ведь можно?

Comment: @Владимир: А зачем вы  в `bindParam()` пытаетесь запихнуть массив или что у вас там несколярное? Покажите, что у вас в массивах `$rows_prepareArray`, `$values_prepareArray` и `$rows_prepare`.

Comment: В массивах у меня имена полей в которые положить имена значений из другого массива, причём у них уже есть :name

Answer (score 1):

`Call to a member function *** on a non-object` обычно говорит о том, что переменная слева от знака -> не является объектом.
Смотрим что возвращает PDO::prepare() — есть вариант **false** вместо объекта, когда сервер не смог подготовить выражение. То есть если у вас в запросе ошибка.

Вам следует для отладки выяснить что за строка запроса получается после подстановки переменных, которых мы здесь не видим. Посмотрите и наверняка увидите ошибку.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $table ($rows) VALUES ($rows_prepare)";
echo $sql; // ОТЛАДКА!!!
$stmt = $this->db->prepare ($sql);
```

**EDIT:**

Для `mysqli::prepare` рецепт тот же. При ошибке вернется false, а это не объект. Отладка вам поможет!

Comment: А если у меня в конструкторе этого класса идёт не PDO а $this -> db = new mysqli(); - может в этом причина? prepare может работать с mysqli ?

Comment: Почитайте документацию. Там всё написано. http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php **Но сути это не меняет — у вас ошибка в запросе, надо выяснить какая**

Comment: Можете помочь барану по скайпу? мой: kylaksizov

Comment: Это вам дорого обойдется. Лучше попробуйте использовать то, что я вам уже посоветовал. И прокомментировать по существу.

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно писать таких функций, от них один вред.

Можно написать функцию, которая принимает **два** аргумента - SQL запрос и массив с данными для плейсхолдеров. Выполнять его надо так:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO table VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->execute($array_with_data);
```

Поскольку в отличие от bindParam, execute() работает с массивами.

Чтобы получить ошибку mysql, которая возникает при вызове prepare(), надо всегда задавать для  PDO режим исключений, как написано [здесь](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo#connect).

также следует отметить, что **в mysqli нет метода bindBaram**. Такой метод есть в PDO. Но чтобы рабтоать с PDO, надо, как это не невероятно звучит, создавать объект не mysqli, а ПДО

Comment: Есть для mysqli bindparam: http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Answer (score -1):

Помню у меня возникала такая проблема, пока я не установил все драйвера. Возможно, не хватает драйвера `mysqlnd` или самого `mysqli`.

Ну и да, `$this->db` - должно возвращать объект stmt. Это можно проверить так: `var_dump($this->db)`